# Reconstructing an array of arrays and turning it into an array of objects with keys as the first array and values as the rest of the array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The question itself is probably in need of editing but hear me out pls.  I have this:

```js
[
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
    ["kiwi", "tomato", "avocado"],
    ["beans", "asparagus", "spinach"]
]
```

I need it so that it will look like the one below:

```js
[
    {"a":"apple", "b":"orange", "c":"banana"},
    {"a":"kiwi", "b":"tomato", "c":"avocado"},
    {"a":"a", "b":"asparagus", "c":"spinach"}
]
```

I have done something like this:

```js
const rows = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
    ["kiwi", "tomato", "avocado"],
    ["beans", "asparagus", "spinach"]
]

const dataObj = {};
const dataArr = [];

if (rows.length) {
        keys = rows[0];
        values = rows[0];

        rows.forEach((element, i) => {
          values = rows[i];
          keys.forEach((key, j) => {
            dataObj[key] = values[j];
            dataArr.push(dataObj);
          });
        });
      }
```

To no avail and got something like this:

```js
[
    {"a":"apple", "b":"orange", "c":"banana"},
    {"a":"apple", "b":"orange", "c":"banana"},
    {"a":"apple", "b":"orange", "c":"banana"}
]
```

This is not the desired output.  If you can help me out - and our community! - it would be super.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use couple of Array functions to achieve this:

- `Array.shift`: To pick the first element and remove it from array
- `Array.map`: To transform items into object

```js
const rows = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
  ["kiwi", "tomato", "avocado"],
  ["beans", "asparagus", "spinach"]
]

const keys = rows.shift();
const map = rows.map((item) => {
  const obj = {}
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    obj[key] = item[index]
  })
  return obj
})

console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `lodash`:
Check it out in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-tester-forked-3oyzg)

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

const input = [
  ["a","b","c"],
  ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
  ["kiwi", "tomato", "avocado"],
  ["beans", "asparagus", "spinach"]
]

const keys = input[0];
const values = input.splice(1);

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);

const output = values.map(row => _.zipObject(keys, row));
console.log(output);
/*
[
  {"a":"apple","b":"orange","c":"banana"}, 
  {"a":"kiwi","b":"tomato","c":"avocado"}, 
  {"a":"beans","b":"asparagus","c":"spinach"}
]
*/
```

Comment: trying to implement this on a nodejs setup.  I might need to require("lodash") - will update!

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code a little bit for the solution

```js
    const rows = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
    ["kiwi", "tomato", "avocado"],
    ["beans", "asparagus", "spinach"]
]

let dataObj = {};
const dataArr = [];

if (rows.length) {
    keys = rows[0];
    rows.forEach((row, i) => {
      if(i==0)
      return
      dataObj = {}
      keys.forEach((key, j) => {
        dataObj[key] = row[j];
      });
      dataArr.push(dataObj);

    });
  }
console.log(dataArr)
```

Comment: I think this was what I was trying to do with my initial code! Thanks man, you definitely nailed what I was trying to do with that code.